# Unexpected behaviour of dplyr::summarise if `across` is used

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to summarise several columns using dplyr, and have found strange results if I include an `across` statement in the `summarise` call. I'm wondering if anyone can help to see why this is happening, and if I'm doing something wrong to cause it.

Test data:

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
test_data <- data.frame(
    group = c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 10), rep(3, 10)),
    yes_no = c(rep(c("Yes", "No"), 15)),
    amount = rnorm(30),
    another_amount = rnorm(30),
    and_another_amount = rnorm(30)
)
```

I can get some group totals. Here I'm doing the same thing 3 different ways, and getting the same results each time.

```
test_data |>
    mutate( amount_if_yes = ifelse(yes_no == "Yes", amount, 0) ) |>
    group_by(group) |>
    summarise(
        sum_all = sum(amount),
        sum_if_yes_1 = sum(amount[ yes_no == "Yes"]),
        sum_if_yes_2 = sum(ifelse(yes_no == "Yes", amount, 0)),
        sum_if_yes_3 = sum(amount_if_yes)
    )

# # A tibble: 3 × 5
#   group sum_all sum_if_yes_1 sum_if_yes_2 sum_if_yes_3
#   <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     1    5.47         5.67         5.67         5.67
# 2     2   -1.63        -2.94        -2.94        -2.94
# 3     3   -1.78         1.62         1.62         1.62
```

I'd also like to run a statement using `across`, so I try doing that at the same time. Unfortunately the first 2 existing `sum` calls now fail, each in their own way, and without a warning. The third (using a pre-made column) still works:

```
test_data |>
    mutate( amount_if_yes = ifelse(yes_no == "Yes", amount, 0) ) |>
    group_by(group) |>
    summarise(
        across(matches("amount"), sum),
        sum_all = sum(amount),
        sum_if_yes_1 = sum(amount[ yes_no == "Yes"]),
        sum_if_yes_2 = sum(ifelse(yes_no == "Yes", amount, 0)),
        sum_if_yes_3 = sum(amount_if_yes)
    )

# # A tibble: 3 × 9
#   group amount another_amount and_another_amount amount_if_yes sum_all sum_if_yes_1 sum_if_yes_2 sum_if_yes_3
#   <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>              <dbl>         <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     1   5.47         -3.64                5.39          5.67    5.47           NA        27.4          5.67
# 2     2  -1.63         -0.202              -2.18         -2.94   -1.63           NA        -8.17        -2.94
# 3     3  -1.78          0.184               2.51          1.62   -1.78           NA        -8.90         1.62
```

To add to the strangeness, if I change the order of the calls within `summarise`, the `sum` calls now work again, presumably because they get evaluated before `across`:

```
test_data |>
    mutate( amount_if_yes = ifelse(yes_no == "Yes", amount, 0) ) |>
    group_by(group) |>
    summarise(
        sum_all = sum(amount),
        sum_if_yes_1 = sum(amount[ yes_no == "Yes"]),
        sum_if_yes_2 = sum(ifelse(yes_no == "Yes", amount, 0)),
        sum_if_yes_3 = sum(amount_if_yes),
        across(matches("amount"), sum)
    )

# # A tibble: 3 × 9
#  group sum_all sum_if_yes_1 sum_if_yes_2 sum_if_yes_3 amount another_amount and_another_amount amount_if_yes
#  <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>              <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1     1    5.47         5.67         5.67         5.67   5.47         -3.64                5.39          5.67
# 2     2   -1.63        -2.94        -2.94        -2.94  -1.63         -0.202              -2.18         -2.94
# 3     3   -1.78         1.62         1.62         1.62  -1.78          0.184               2.51          1.62
```

So my question is, why does using `across` affect the other functions? Am I doing something wrong or is this an unexpected behaviour?

EDIT TO ADD after comment from @RitchieSacramento:
Note this is not specific to `across`, but also happens in `summarise` even if those columns that `across` would have created are instead created explicitly (note different results for 3 different summing methods):

```
test_data |>
    mutate( amount_if_yes = ifelse(yes_no == "Yes", amount, 0) ) |>
    group_by(group) |>
    summarise(
        amount = sum(amount),
        another_amount = sum(another_amount),
        and_another_amount = sum(and_another_amount),
        amount_if_yes = sum(amount_if_yes),
        sum_all = sum(amount),
        sum_if_yes_1 = sum(amount[ yes_no == "Yes"]),
        sum_if_yes_2 = sum(ifelse(yes_no == "Yes", amount, 0)),
        sum_if_yes_3 = sum(amount_if_yes)
    ) |>
    select(group, sum_if_yes_1, sum_if_yes_2, sum_if_yes_3)

# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#   group sum_if_yes_1 sum_if_yes_2 sum_if_yes_3
#   <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
# 1     1           NA        27.4          5.67
# 2     2           NA        -8.17        -2.94
# 3     3           NA        -8.90         1.62
```

Worth noting too that `data.table` seems to behave differently, such that order of evaluation within the one "group by" call doesn't matter (note same results regardless for each of the 3 methods):

```
setDT(test_data)[
    , amount_if_yes := ifelse(yes_no == "Yes", amount, 0)
][
    , .( amount = sum(amount),
         another_amount = sum(another_amount),
         and_another_amount = sum(and_another_amount),
         amount_if_yes = sum(amount_if_yes),
         sum_all = sum(amount),
         sum_if_yes_1 = sum(amount[ yes_no == "Yes"]),
         sum_if_yes_2 = sum(ifelse(yes_no == "Yes", amount, 0)),
         sum_if_yes_3 = sum(amount_if_yes) ),
    by = group
][ , .(group, sum_if_yes_1, sum_if_yes_2, sum_if_yes_3) ]

#    group sum_if_yes_1 sum_if_yes_2 sum_if_yes_3
# 1:     1     5.668301     5.668301     5.668301
# 2:     2    -2.942032    -2.942032    -2.942032
# 3:     3     1.619465     1.619465     1.619465
```

Comment: This is the expected behavior - the `across()` call replaces those columns with the calculated value and these values are then used in the subsequent calculations.  This sequential calculation is a feature not a bug in `dplyr` but can present a bit of a gotcha. You can avoid it by doing the `across()` call last as you noted in  your post, or by using the `.names` argument so new, differently named, columns are created.

Comment: Thanks @RitchieSacramento, that's interesting. I had assumed `summarise` would create a new table with matching/specified column names for output, rather than overwriting the existing columns. I see now that even if I specify the `across` statement more explicitly (`amount = sum(amount), another_amount =...`) the same thing happens (subsequent columns are evaluated from already summarised columns rather than the input colums). This is definitely not what I expected!

Comment: Note that tucked away in the examples in the `summarize()` documentation is this note `# BEWARE: reusing variables may lead to unexpected results` but it may not be immediately clear that an `across()` call (without changing the name) is a use of the variable which impacts subsequent uses.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento yep, I wish I'd seen/known that warning before! Thank you for the help. Please feel free to post an answer so I can accept it if you'd like to (up to you).